# Write a progress of async compressing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, compression, task

I have this code:

```
using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(compressedFile))
    {
        using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(targetStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Compress of file{0} is end. Inintial size: {1}  compressed size: {2}.",
                sourceFile,
                sourceStream.Length.ToString(),
                targetStream.Length.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to write asynchronously the progress of compressiong files. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `CopyToAsync`? Have you researched how to report progress asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

First find the size of the source file. Then progress is the number of input bytes from the source file consumed so far, divided by the size of the source file.